# How to get a node list according to the parameter from the previous pipeline job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got 2 pipeline jobs.

Jenkinsfile in the first one:

```
slave_list = ['test01', 'test02']
build job: 'pipeline-test2', parameters: [[$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'node_list', labels: slave_list, nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
```

Jenkinsfile in the second one:

```
echo node_list
for (slave in node_list) {
    echo slave
}
```

tip: the name of the second job is "pipeline-test2", and "node_list" is a parameter of List type.

the first job triggers the second one, and the output of the second job is:

```
[Pipeline] echo
test01
[Pipeline] echo
t
[Pipeline] echo
e
[Pipeline] echo
s
[Pipeline] echo
t
[Pipeline] echo
0
[Pipeline] echo
1
```

why the second job receives only one parameter:test01? I want the second job to receive a list(slave_list) from the first one? and how to complete it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a normal behavior based on the Jenkins doc.

```
 Defines a list of nodes where this job could potentially be executed on. 

 The  job can be executed on multiple nodes/slaves, one after the other
 (concurrent execution is currently not supported).
```

So each time, Jenkins will only choose one node (That's why you can only see node 1) to run whatever how many nodes you passed in.

If you really want to get node list, you can pass it as a normal parameters instead of node parameter.

Br,

Tim

Comment: Thank Tim very much!!  I want to trigger a job to run in many nodes concurrently, If I pass a normal parameters instead of the node parameter, I only run the job in the node one by one, such as using for clause. Could you tell me how to trigger a job concurrently in many nodes?

Comment: Hi, what you did is correct, if you the pipeline1 a lot of times, you will find some of them are running in slave1, some of them are running in slave2